# Save javaRDD as XML file

Tags: java, xml, apache-spark, text-files

Is there any way in Apache Spark to save a java RDD of text as an XML file?

What I do currently is save the RDD as a plain text file using **saveAsTextFile** method and then convert it to XML. 
I am interested to find a way to directly create the XML file from RDD.

Any tip, idea or guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer databricks xml library to read and write data from/to xml. Inferring schema from data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .load("books.xml");

df.select("author", "_id").write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rootTag", "books")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .save("newbooks.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you @FaigB for your help. I implemented my code following your solution but I got following error on the **save** step. 


`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource.createRelation(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/sources/BaseRelation;`

Any idea?

Comment: What is version of spark you are using ?

Comment: I use Spark 2.2.0 and spark-xml_2-10 version 0.4.1 as dependancy